# Creating a hierarchy of JSON schemas

Tags: json

I'm working on structuring some JSON data with information from different types of sources. I am focusing on only one type of source, documents, and I have a few data points collected and ready. So I decided I should try and write a JSON schema for data regarding the documents.

The first four properties, id, name, type and url must be present regardless of the type of source, but the other information contained in each varies. I would like to store all of them in the same database though. I suppose it will be of interest to write a schema for each of the other types of sources at a later point.

I am quite new to working with JSON, and the difficulty at the moment is understanding how I can fit these schemas together. What is the best practice? Is it possible to create a hierarchy of these different object types with a top level schema containing the information below and second level schemas for each type? Or is it better to make a larger schema containing all the information that could be present in all the different types of sources?

```
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
"title": "Document",
"description": "Information connected to a document",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "id": {
        "description": "The unique identifier",
        "type": "number"
    },
    "name": {
        "description": "Title of the source",
        "type": "string"
    },
    "type": {
        "description": "Type of source",
        "type": "string"
    },
    "url": {
        "description": "URL of the source",
        "type": "string"
    }, 
    "morePropertiesHere": {
        "description": "the rest of the properties vary depending on type of source"
    }
},
"required": ["id", "name", "type", "url"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the properties part in JSON like this, as it takes only number and text.

"properties": {
    "id":1234,
    "name":"Name of the source",
    "description": "Title of the source",
    "type": "Type of source",
    "url": "URL of the source",
    "morePropertiesHere": {
        "description": "the rest of the properties vary depending on type of source"
    }
}
If Id's are numbers then you can give them as it is instead of putting inside "".

Comment: The code example is intended to be viewed as a schema, not a data point.   The line "type": "number" signifies that the data element id should have type number.

Comment: To clarify further, a data point might look like this:

`{
    “id”: 123456,
    “name”: “source 1 title”,
    “type”: “document”,
    “url”: “www.somesite.com“,
    “morePropertiesHere”: “this is another property, but I could just as well have omitted it”
}`

Comment: Okay,got it.In this case you can have it as full schema containing all the information and refer to the same property.

Comment: Hm, well some of the data sources I have contain around 100-150 different possible attributes. I have around 3-5 sources at the moment, but more might be added in the future. Creating a large schema for all of them will not make the document very readable. I would prefer to make a schema for each, but I have not figured out if this is possible to do yet. Do you know if it is possible to create different schemas for each and link them together? Why do you think creating one schema for all sources is better?

Comment: I thought that the maximum number of data you had was around 30-50,so suggested to have it as a single full schema.One quick question, are you entering the values for each and every property?

Comment: Well, some of the attributes might not be available for every object, but definitely more than half. I have been trying to stick to [Google's styleguide for JSON](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml), but I have not yet decided if I should omit attributes which are null (as suggested in the styleguide) or if I should keep them.

Comment: Hmm,so far I've used maximum of 30-40 data.I'll also look into this scenario. :)